# What is the word for someone who has earned the position to do what they worked for?

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought the word was credibility, but that was not it.

The word should fit in this sentence:
After we finish our psychology class, we should be _____ to diagnose her with compulsive lying disorder.

Comment: I would use "qualified", as Jason Bassford has said. Also the word "diagnosis" in the OP should have been "diagnose".

Answer (score 4):

[**Qualified**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qualified):

[Merriam-Webster]

> **1 a** : fitted (as by training or experience) for a given purpose : COMPETENT
>   **b** : having complied with the specific requirements or precedent conditions (as for an office or employment) : ELIGIBLE

Comment: "Qualified" makes sense as an answer to the question title. For the example sentence however, I would use "competent".

Answer (score 1):

I would have said "qualified," but "competent" is probably better.  Also, the question mistakenly uses the word "whose" where "who's" or "who is" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "qualified" has connotations of being authorized by some authority or governing body, while "competent" merely speaks to the required skills.

Answer (score 0):

**[Trusted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trusted)**

[Merriam-Webster]

> **1 a** : assured reliance on the character, ability, strength, or truth of someone or something
>   **b** : one in which confidence is placed